# Table contents not in good shape

Tags: tables, multicolumn, width, text, fit

[image]

```
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|Y|}
  \hline

& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Table.1 : Low birth weight and fuel choice}\\ 
\hline
\textbf{Author}        & \textbf{Region}                  & \textbf{Method}                                                  & \textbf{Major Findings}                                                                                                                                             \\ 
\hline
(Li et al., 2017)      & Cross-countries                  & Meta analysis, Pooled Odd ratio, Relative risk, and hazard ratio & 10-unit increment of particulate matter led 5\% and 2\% higher chance of low birth weight and preterm birth, respectively during pregnancy                          \\ 
\hline
Bruce et al., 2013     & 155 countries, from 1974 to 2010 & Meta analysis, Pooled Odd ratio                                  & meta-analysis found links between moderate stunting and severe stunting and exposure to home air pollution, which was defined as the use of solid fuel for cooking  \\ 
\hline
(Liu et al., 2020)     & China                            & Propensity Score Matching                                        & non-solid fuels for cooking helps respondents' living activities without any assistance by between 1.33-1.42\% without assistance by between 3.02-3.40\%            \\ 
\hline
(Islam  Mohanty, 2021) & India                            & estimating mean birth weight                                     & the risk of childhood stunting was considerably increased by 16\% for children under-5                                                                              \\ 
\hline
(Ahmed et al., 2021)   & Bangladesh                       & Adjusted odd ratio                                               & Due to use of bio-mass fuel,  prevalence of wasting, underweight, and stunting increased by 16.1\%, 39\% and 43.3\%                                                 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to form a table that has 4 columns and fits with page width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has errors in it. You only specify two columns, but most rows have four, and the first one has 5 since there's a `&` before the four column `\multicolumn`. Nothing will appear correctly until those problems are fixed.

I'd recommend loading the [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=en) package, which makes complex tables easier. In particular, you can use `X` style columns with options in brackets like `c` for centering (`l` for left aligning) and `co=` for setting an expansion coefficient. (Those with `co=2` are twice as wide as those with `co=1`, for example.)

Here's a first pass at fixing your problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption={Low birth weight and fuel choice}
]{
colspec={X[co=1,c]X[co=1,c]X[co=2,l]X[co=3,l]},
hlines,vlines
}
\textbf{Author} & \textbf{Region} & \textbf{Method} & \textbf{Major Findings} \\ 
(Li et al., 2017) & Cross-countries & Meta analysis, Pooled Odd ratio, Relative risk, and hazard ratio & 10-unit increment of particulate matter led 5\% and 2\% higher chance of low birth weight and preterm birth, respectively during pregnancy \\ 
Bruce et al., 2013 & 155 countries, from 1974 to 2010 & Meta analysis, Pooled Odd ratio & meta-analysis found links between moderate stunting and severe stunting and exposure to home air pollution, which was defined as the use of solid fuel for cooking \\ 
(Liu et al., 2020) & China & Propensity Score Matching & non-solid fuels for cooking helps respondents' living activities without any assistance by between 1.33-1.42\% without assistance by between 3.02-3.40\% \\ 
(Islam Mohanty, 2021) & India & estimating mean birth weight & the risk of childhood stunting was considerably increased by 16\% for children under-5 \\ 
(Ahmed et al., 2021) & Bang\-ladesh & Adjusted odd ratio & Due to use of bio-mass fuel, prevalence of wasting, underweight, and stunting increased by 16.1\%, 39\% and 43.3\% \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: longtblr]

But you might read the package documentation and look into things like its booktabs library, which might improve the aesthetics by a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

with `xltabular` it allows a pagebreak, if needed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|X|X|}  
\caption{Low birth weight and fuel choice}\\        \hline
\textbf{Author}   & \textbf{Region} & \textbf{Method}   & \textbf{Major Findings}     \\ \hline
(Li et al., 2017) & Cross-countries & Meta analysis, Pooled Odd ratio, Relative risk, and hazard ratio 
        & 10-unit increment of particulate matter led 5\% and 2\% higher chance of low birth weight 
           and preterm birth, respectively during pregnancy  \\ \hline
Bruce et al., 2013& 155 countries, from 1974 to 2010 & Meta analysis, Pooled Odd ratio                                  & meta-analysis found links between moderate stunting and severe stunting and exposure to home air pollution, which was defined as the use of solid fuel for cooking  \\ 
    \hline
    (Liu et al., 2020)     & China                            & Propensity Score Matching                                        & non-solid fuels for cooking helps respondents' living activities without any assistance by between 1.33-1.42\% without assistance by between 3.02-3.40\%            \\ 
    \hline
    (Islam  Mohanty, 2021) & India                            & estimating mean birth weight                                     & the risk of childhood stunting was considerably increased by 16\% for children under-5                                                                              \\ 
    \hline
    (Ahmed et al., 2021)   & Bangladesh                       & Adjusted odd ratio                                               & Due to use of bio-mass fuel,  prevalence of wasting, underweight, and stunting increased by 16.1\%, 39\% and 43.3\%  \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]